# Delete all keys in a bucket of s3 which are three days old using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, boto

How do I delete all the keys in an S3 bucket which are three days old using python?

S3 bucket contents are like:

```
mybucket001/backup/1566394660_21_08_2019_backup
mybucket001/backup/1566394660_20_08_2019_backup
mybucket001/backup/1566394660_19_08_2019_backup
mybucket001/backup/1566394660_18_08_2019_backup
```

I need to keep only the last two days of data.

Here is what I tried:

```
import boto

from boto.s3.key import Key

keyId='***'
sKeyId='***'

srcFileName="file name" #Name of the file to be deleted

bucketName="bucket name" #Name of the bucket, where the file resides

conn = boto.connect_s3(keyId,sKeyId) #Connect to S3

bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucketName) #Get the bucket object

k = Key(bucket,srcFileName) #Get the key of the given object

k.delete()
```

Comment: These days it is recommended to use `boto3` rather than `boto`.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than doing this via code, you could simply configure [Amazon S3 Object Lifecycle Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) to delete the objects after 3 days.

Comment: can we do that using python

Comment: You mean configure the Object Lifecycle policy using Python? Yes. Everything in AWS can be done from code. See: [`put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration)

Comment: how to configure for a particular key in bucket and set only files that are two days old should be deleted

Comment: You'll need to follow the documentation. If you have a specific problem, feel free to post a new Question.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a slightly odd way to use `boto` and S3; I would set up an S3 client:

```
 import boto3
 import datetime
 s3 = boto3.client('s3')
```

then use the [boto API to list the files in the bucket](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2) (assuming the bucket exists):

```
files = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket='my-bucket')['Contents']
```

which will give you a list of dictionaries, each corresponding to one object/file.

You can then filter this list by modified date and extract the keys:

```
old_files = [{'Key': file['Key']} for file in files if file['LastModified'] < datetime.now() - timedelta(days=2)]
```

and then again [use the API](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.delete_objects) to delete a certain portion of those files:

```
 s3.delete_objects(Bucket='my-bucket', Delete={'Objects': old_files})
```

Comment: TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

Comment: how to select the keys inside the bucket @danimal

Comment: did you fix the datetime problem?

Comment: yes fixed that.  mybucket001 has many keys . I need to select backups folder and do the operation

Comment: My `files` variable is a list of python dictionaries, with each dict having a key 'Key' so that the `old_files` will contain dictionaries but with *only* the key - does that make sense?

Comment: To avoid the TypeError, use: `datetime.now().astimezone() - timedelta(days=2)`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
import boto
from datetime import datetime
from boto.s3.key import Key

keyId='***'
sKeyId='***'

srcFileName="file name" #Name of the file to be deleted

bucketName="bucket name" #Name of the bucket, where the file resides

conn = boto.connect_s3(keyId,sKeyId) #Connect to S3

bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucketName) #Get the bucket object

k = Key(bucket,srcFileName) #Get the key of the given object
today = datetime.now().day  # Get current day
if today - int(k.split('_')[1]) >= 2:  # check the day difference for the last 2 days
    k.delete()
```

run for every key

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry at all about the deletion as S3 itself will take that headache for you.

Ref https://aws.amazon.com/.../aws/amazon-s3-object-expiration/